# OBIEE: filter that supports "LIKE" and "IN"

Tags: filter, sql-like, prompt, obiee

OBIEE:  How can I make a filter that supports "LIKE" and "IN", so for example, the user can enter in the analysis prompt either A3%  or  A31;A34;A3C

1) This works for IN: UPPER("Fund Status - Direct"."Proj Nbr") IN (@{V_PROJ_NUMBER}[UPPER('@')]{UPPER("Fund Status - Direct"."Proj Nbr")})

2) This works for LIKE: UPPER("Fund Status - Direct"."Proj Nbr") LIKE (@{V_PROJ_NUMBER} [UPPER('@%')]{UPPER("Fund Status - Direct"."Proj Nbr")})

3) When I try to combine them in the Criteria filters, the LIKE filter crashes when user enters a delimited string such as A1;A2

Comment: Edit your post to include the information above please

Answer (score 0):

a) Having to force UPPER clearly states a data issue which should be adressed beforehand. This isn't helpful in self-service analytics.

b) You know that you can configure prompts so that the user himself can choose the operand?

c) You know that OBIEE also does google-style typeahead prompts? But that of course is something which will always work better when your data is well defined and no crutches like UPPER come into play.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/biee/BIEUG/prompts.htm#BIEUG11854

This was introduced in 2010.

tl;dr - always give preference to out-of-the-box functionalities and try to tackle issues at their root rshter than hacking around the issues with custom code

Comment: a) When the user can type in a partial string to match on (s%), if they use lowercase, but the data is all uppercase, it will fail.  How do you deal with that, if you don't force the input to uppercase?  I wish OBIEE would provide case-insensitive searching when the user enters the search string, but I don't see a way.  b)  omg, I totally forgot about the option to let the user choose.  Thanks for that!  c)  I'll have to look into the typeahead.  Thanks for your responses.

Comment: "Match All — As the user types, Oracle BI EE suggests the column values that contain any letter that the user is typing. For example, if the administrator configured auto-complete to be case-insensitive and the matching level to Match All and the user types "l," then Oracle BI EE suggests "LCD 36X Standard," "LCD HD Television," "7 Megapixel Digital Camera," and "Plasma HD Television.""

Comment: Also: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/biee/BIESG/GUID-FF6954BA-2DE0-4422-BA58-05F32936F4FF.htm#BIESG3734
"<CaseInsensitive>true</CaseInsensitive>"

Comment: Also: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/biee/BIESG/GUID-4F5B5A4F-0C4B-4494-88C1-970DFB23537B.htm#BIESG335
"Set CASE_SENSITIVE_CHARACTER_COMPARISON to correspond with how the back-end database deals with case. For example, if the back-end database is case-insensitive, then configure the Oracle BI Server to be case-insensitive. If the Oracle BI Server and the back-end database are not similarly case-sensitive, then some subtle problems can result."

As I said it is always better to first look at out-of-the-box things :)

Comment: And before I forget: If you prepare a forced UPPER column in the RPD then you will always be using it the same way wherever it comes into play and don't have to fiddle around with column formulas and prompts formulas 50 times for 50 use cases.